# Nuget Install performance

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

I have a VS2012 solution with 134 projects. I have a local Nuget repository (as in C:...\NuGetMirror) with about 50 packages, which is the only active package source. One of my packages has 21 DLLs in it, and depends on two other local packages, with a handful of DLLs each. One of htose has one further dependency. I am trying to use the package manager to install the package into about 120 of the projects (right-click the solution, Manage nuget packages for solution, select the package, tick the projects I want it in). It took nearly 2 hours. The projects already have one of the dependent packages installed. There is no network activity according to Wireshark.  Nuget package manager extension version 2.8.50126.400.

So, questions:

1. Is this "normal"?
2. What can I do to improve it?

I realise 20-odd DLLs in a package is probably not "best practice", but it makes sense here and if it's going to take 2 hours to install every package I want as few as possible...

Answer (score 0):

Disabling Resharper made it much faster. Still around 20 minutes but much faster.